# C program printing symbols and zeros into file instead on letters

Tags: c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    double t1[100], t2[100], t3[100], hw1[100], hw2[100], hw3[100], hw4[100], prj[100];
    char name[100][50];
    char id[100][8];
    int i;

    FILE * fpt;
    FILE * frt;

    fpt = fopen("project1.txt", "r");
    frt = fopen("result1.txt", "w");

    if ((fpt = fopen("project1.txt", "r")) == EOF) {
      printf("ERROR, cant't open input file\n");
    } else {
      printf("Please refer to result text file to see the result. Thank you\n");

      for (i = 1; i <= 68; i++) {
        fscanf(fpt, "%s%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f", & name[i], & id[i], & t1[i], & t2[i], & t3[i], & hw1[i], & hw2[i], & hw3[i], & hw4[i], & prj[i]);
        fprintf(frt, "%s%5s%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f\n", name[i], id[i], t1[i], t2[i], t3[i], hw1[i], hw2[i], hw3[i], hw4[i], prj[i]);
      }
    }

    fclose(fpt);
    fclose(frt);

    system("pause");
}
```

I created this file to read students' names, ID, and results(for tests, home works, etc) from a file and print in another file, but it ended up printing weird symbols and zeros in that file. Why is it so and how to fix it? (Btw I'm a beginner) Thanks in advance

Comment: `fopen` does not return `EOF` upon failure, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: You should check the return value of `fscanf`

Comment: But when I set it to NULL, it's not reading anything from the input file

Comment: `%s` does not read/save spaces.  `char id[100][8];` likely too small.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: nit: try to avoid saying: `for (i = 1; i <= 68; i++)`  and opt for `for (i = 0; i < 68; i++)`  Unless you are doing something special, start counting at 0.

Comment: @TomCruise Do: `fpt = fopen("project1.txt", "r"); if(fpt==NULL) abort();`.  or similar on every occasion where you do not currently check for failures.

Comment: Guys, I tried all of your suggestions but it keeps printing symbols and zeros into the file

Comment: "But when I set it to NULL, it's not reading anything from the input file" Two wrongs do not make a right, `EOF` is a mistake. You have called `fopen` on that file already, just compare the pointer directly.

Comment: Yeah I have changed it (fpt == NULL), but it does seem like there's a problem in the output file or the code related to that as it keeps printing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

```
// use int
// main() {
int main() {
    // Avoid naked magic mumbers
    // double t1[100], t2[100], t3[100], hw1[100], hw2[100], hw3[100], hw4[100], prj[100];
    #define N 100
    double t1[N], t2[N], t3[N], hw1[N], hw2[N], hw3[N], hw4[N], prj[N];
    // char name[100][50]; char id[100][8];
    char name[N][50]; char id[N][8];
    int i;

    FILE * fpt;
    FILE * frt;

    fpt = fopen("project1.txt", "r");
    // Add proper test
    if (fpt == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR, can't open input file project\n");
      return -1;
    }

    frt = fopen("result1.txt", "w");
    // Add proper test
    if (frt == NULL) {
      fclose(fpt)
      printf("ERROR, can't open output file result\n");
      return -1;
    }

    //if ((fpt = fopen("project1.txt", "r")) == EOF) {
    //  printf("ERROR, cant't open input file\n");
    //} else {
    //  printf("Please refer to result text file to see the result. Thank you\n");

    // Index from 0      
    //  for (i = 1; i <= 68; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      // fscanf(fpt, "%s%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f", & name[i], & id[i], & t1[i], & t2[i], & t3[i], & hw1[i], & hw2[i], & hw3[i], & hw4[i], & prj[i]);
      // Use width limits on strings, test return value, proper type, specifier
      if (fscanf(fpt, "%49s%7s%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", 
          name[i], id[i], &t1[i], &t2[i], &t3[i], 
          &hw1[i], &hw2[i], &hw3[i], &hw4[i], &prj[i]) != 10) {
        break;
      }
      fprintf(frt, "%s%5s%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f\n", 
          name[i], id[i], t1[i], t2[i], t3[i], 
          hw1[i], hw2[i], hw3[i], hw4[i], prj[i]);
      }
    }

    fclose(fpt);
    fclose(frt);

    system("pause")
}
```

If the name has spaces, code still needs more work.

Other improvements possible, yet need to know more about the data.